# How to get the storage class of an object stored in aws bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage-class-specifier

I need to check the storage class of an object inside an S3 bucket.

Is there a way to get the storage class of an S3 object using the AWS CLI v2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [list-objects-v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html).

For example:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket <bucket-name> --prefix <object_key> --query "Contents[*].StorageClass" --output text
```

Output:

```
GLACIER
```

Comment: Hello. Is there a way to return storage class for multiple objects? For example, I have objects stored for 10 years (partitioned as year=,month=day=)... I want to check all objects. Is that possible? I tried the following to maybe return a year at a time:aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket my-bucket --prefix folder/year=2022/* --query "Contents[*].StorageClass" --output text --profile dev. This did not work.